# Why does this code miss the first entry?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, phpmyadmin

Ok, I have a little problem with my code: it doesn't get the first result?
For example: the ban table may look like this:
[https://i.stack.imgur.com/dYuCd.png][1]
But it the data echoed will miss that first row, the one with the reason RDMx3 and Evade, and with no name.

For example: here is direct from SourceBans:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/Snxzv.png

And here is the version using the below code:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/eCexb.png

Note that the first ban, displayed on the first image, is not displayed on the second image. (Don't mind the length on the second image, I've gotta fix that.)

```
<?php
$sql44 = "SELECT * FROM `sb_bans` ORDER BY `created` DESC LIMIT 6";
$res44 = mysqli_query($GLOBALS["___mysqli_ston"], $sql44) or trigger_error(((is_object($GLOBALS["___mysqli_ston"])) ? mysqli_error($GLOBALS["___mysqli_ston"]) : (($___mysqli_res = mysqli_connect_error()) ? $___mysqli_res : false)));
$row44 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($res44);

while($row44 = mysqli_fetch_array($res44))
{
$sid1 = $row44['sid'];
$name1 = $row44['name'];
$steamid110 = $row44['authid'];
$reason1 = $row44['reason'];
$timesec = $row44['length'];
$unbanstatus = $row44['RemoveType'];

if($unbanstatus == "U")
{
$type1 = "(U)";
}
elseif($unbanstatus == "E")
{
$type1 = "(E)";
}
else
{
$type1 = "";
}
if($sid = 1)
{
$serv = "<img src='http://bans.versound.net/images/games/gmodttt.png' alt='TTT' />";
}
elseif($sid = 2)
{
$serv = "TF2 AU";
}
elseif($sid = 3)
{
$serv = "SB AU";
}
else
{
$serv = "wtf";
}
if($name1 == NULL)
{
$name1 = "no nickname present";
}
else
{
$name1 = $name1;
}
if($timesec == "0")
{
$length1 = "Permanent";
}
else
{
$length2 = gmdate("d", $timesec);
$length1 = "$length2 days";
}
echo "<tr style='" . $type2 . "'>\n<td style='text-align:center'>" . $serv . "</td>\n<td><a href='http://bans.versound.net/index.php?p=banlist&amp;advSearch=" . $steamid110 . "&amp;advType=steamid&amp;Submit' target='_blank'>" . $name1 . "</a></td>\n<td>" . $reason1 . "</td>\n<td>" . $length1 . " " . $type1 . "</td>\n</tr>\n";
}
?>
```

Why does this occur? Can you help me? Also, I use DESC LIMIT 6 because DESC LIMIT 5 misses the first result, and only outputs 4 results.

Answer (score 2):

Because you are calling one `fetch` unnecessarily and wasting it before calling the real fetch that you use.

```
$row44 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($res44);  //This line is not needed and should go

while($row44 = mysqli_fetch_array($res44))
```

Should simply be

```
while($row44 = mysqli_fetch_array($res44))
```

Answer (score -1):

Isn't the query($sql44) supposed to come first before the connection(I suppose $GLOBALS["___mysqli_ston"]) in the mysqli_query?

Comment: Nope it isn't supposed to be like that